# How do I get twitter bootstrap datepicker to work in ie7?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-7, datepicker

My company works in the past. All my users for my app have to use ie7. How do I get the twitter bootstrap datepicker to work with IE7. It works fine in IE8+ chrome, firefox, and safari. But my users are not allowed to use anything but IE7.

When I click the textbox with the datepicker I get the dropdown box and its about 2px in length and 50px in width. but there is no calendar displaying.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide your code, preferably in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I have never used that before but I will try and post it

Comment: @sarah http://jsfiddle.net/S5UFa/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [ajbeaven's fix](https://github.com/ajbeaven/bootstrap-datepicker/commit/9dd88f143ea50e5a85d4a58566c4ecee26ac480b) from [this issue](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/pull/170), although it hasn't been merged into the plugin yet.

Change line 185 from

```
 return $(this).css('z-index') != 'auto';
```

to

```
var itemZIndex = $(this).css('z-index');
return itemZIndex != 'auto' && itemZIndex !== 0;
```

Comment: What file are did you find that line of code in? I have searched the bootstrap-datepicker.js and I did not find it.

Comment: My mistake, I assumed you were using [eternicode's fork](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) of bootstrap-datepicker, which is far more actively maintained than the original. I was unable to find a support forum or any mention of that bug for the original version.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the bootstrap plugin, just add this class to your css after the bootstrap datetimepicker css file:

```
.datetimepicker table tr td span {
    width: 200%!important;
}
```